# Laravel sanctum SPA - This set-cookie domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url

Tags: laravel-sanctum

I have a VueJS app and a Laravel API in separated projects.
I have some issues to auth with laravel sanctum.
My VueJs is on localhost:8080 and my API on localhost:8000

When i try to set cookie, i have a "This set-cookie domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url" issue

I think that laravel cant set cookie, when i try to auth he returned a 419 error status which mean token mismatch.

My config/cors.php

```
   'paths' => [
        'api/*',
        'sanctum/csrf-cookie',
        'login',
        'logout'
    ],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

I follow the laravel documentation.

Add theses lines to my app/Http/Kernel.php

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful;

'api' => [
    EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
    'throttle:api',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

I activated axios credentials in my vue app

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

I set my SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost:8080.

In my VueJS login component :

```
       axios
          .get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
          .then(response => {
            axios.post('/login', {
              email : 'alexandria96@example.com',
              password : 'password'
            }).then(response => {
                console.log('User signed in!');
            }).catch(error => console.log(error)); // credentials didn't match
      });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCjcq.png)

The request for csrf-cookie
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyhOg.png)

The request for login
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQWNi.png)

Answer (score 3):

Before logging in you have to check that cookie are setted. Your cookie is not set that's why you have 419 error.
Try to take away ports from configs.
Try

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost
```

And now check cookies. For me works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Also, your issue might be your SESSION_DOMAIN value. change it from ".localhost" to "localhost"
```

Your cookies will be blocked by browser if the domain is ".localhost".